# jQuery ajax not working after second call in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery, caching

I have problems like many others wit IE and probably caching. I have an auction site and when user clicks on bid, **fires this code**:

```
function bid(id){
var end_dateUP=0;

var tupdate=jq("#tupdate"+id).val();

if (tupdate=="lvl1"){
    end_dateUP=20;  
}else if (tupdate=="lvl2"){
    end_dateUP=15;  
}else if (tupdate=="lvl3"){
    end_dateUP=10;  
}else{
    end_dateUP=0;
}

var url = "http://localhost/bid/comet/update-auction.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.
var user_id=<?php echo json_encode($user_id);?>; //here i'm getting id from SESSION
var user_name=<?php echo json_encode($user_name); ?>; //here i'm getting user name from SESSION
jq.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    url: url,
    data: {"auct_id" : id, "user_id" : user_id, "username" : user_name, "end_date" : end_dateUP}, // serializes the form's elements.
    cache:false,
    success: function(data)
    {
        setTimeout('waitForMsg()',100);
        jq("#tupdate"+id).val("");  
        jq('#bid-container'+id).animate({ backgroundColor: "#659ae0" }, 50);
        jq('#bid-container'+id).animate({ backgroundColor: "#FFF" }, 500);

    },
    error: function(xhr, errorString, exception) {
        alert("xhr.status="+xhr.status+" error="+errorString+" exception=|"+exception+"|");
    }
});
}
```

**and in PHP (update-auction.php) I get this posted ajax data and I update my database:**

```
$auction_id=$_POST['auct_id'];
$user_id=$_POST['user_id'];
$usr=$_POST['username'];
$enddate=$_POST['end_date'];


//Database update
```

**This code works great in Firefox or Chrome.**
**So the problem is**, when I click on bid first time, it works, but when I go to second page (code below):

```
function pageClick(page){
var url = "http://localhost/bid/auctions-ajax"; // the script where you handle the form input.  

jq.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); //this line before $.ajax!!!
    jq.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: {"page" : page}, 
           async:false, //to sem dodal za časovni zamik
           cache: false,
           success: function(data)
           {
             jq("#a_loader").hide();  
             jq("#show-category").html(data); // show response from the php script.              
           },
            error: function(xhr, errorString, exception) {
            alert("xhr.status="+xhr.status+" error="+errorString+" exception=|"+exception+"|");
        }
    });

}
```

(onClick which fires ajax call and shows second page) then this `function bid(id)` stops working. I've searched for solutions like, `cache:false,` adding `new Date().time();` to post and posting data in JSON but with no luck. 
(Also when I tried to post data in JSON format I've got some Syntax errors: Unexpected token < and parse error and so one). I'm just trying to figure out the simplest solution with this working code... Any ideas?

Comment: How do you "go to the second page"? Are you modifying the DOM, and replacing the element that has the click handler? Then you need to re-bind the handler, or use delegation with `.on()`.

Comment: I have updated post and added code how I go to second page...

Comment: Is the bid inside `#show-category`?

Comment: Yes. With pageClick () I post the page number to auctions-ajax (php file), which returns-echoes output from database (sorted in this case by page),  a complete auction (with complete I mean that the output is designed with css and so one..) Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found solution. Internet Explorer had problem with jquery animation. I had some old one, which was causing problem and not executing the script fully. I have to include latest `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>` to work in IE. Now works great.

Answer (score 2):

This solved my problem:

```
$.ajax(url,
{
cache: false,
success: function(){
//do something
}
}
);
```

"The reason is that, some browsers cach the result as long as the request is the same in the get request."

Example:

```
function showBootstrapModalPopup(url, containerId, modalId)
{
        $.ajax(url,
        {
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                //do something
                $('#' + containerId).html(data);

                $('#' + modalId).modal('show');
            }
        }
        );


    //$.ajax({
    //    url: url,
    //    success: function (data) {
    //        $('#' + containerId).html(data);

    //        $('#' + modalId).modal('show');
    //    },
    //    cache: false
    //});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're currently binding the click handler with:

```
$("selector").click(function...);
```

change it to:

```
$("#show-category").on("click", "selector", function ...);
```

This is necessary because `pageClick()` replaces the DOM elements that had the click bindings before. You need to use delegation from a parent element that is retained across the page replacement.

Comment: Hm.. But I don't have "click" function like you said -> `$("selector").click(function...);` . The page is called in auctions-ajax php file like this: `<a href='javascript:void()' onClick='pageClick(1)'></a>` in this exaple goes to first page. And then this `function pageClick(page)` executes... Thank you for helping!

Comment: That's the code for going to the next page. How are you binding the function to click on a bid, is that also with `onclick`? Is that binding in the HTML you load with AJAX?

Comment: Yes, also in ajax -> auctions-ajax php file. When I click BID button `<a class="bid-button" id="bid-button'.$r['id'].'" href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="bid('.$r['id'].');return false;">BID</a>`, it fires then this javascript `function bid(id)`

Comment: Without seeing everything in context, it's really hard to guess what's going wrong in your application. Do you see any errors in the console? When you look at the DOM in the inspector, do you see the `onclick` attribute, and does it have the correct argument?

Comment: `onClick` should be `onclick`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28029/discussion-between-matjaz-zeleznik-and-barmar)